# I can't call a method when i click a menuitem in prime faces

Tags: jsf, primefaces

my problem is that i can't call a method when i click the menuitem inside a menu. This is the xhtml:

```
<p:column styleClass="cm-col-width-35">
     <p:commandButton id="dynaButton" type="button"
        styleClass="cm-button-menu" icon="ui-icon-triangle-1-s" />
     <p:menu overlay="true" trigger="dynaButton" my="left top"
        style="width:200px;" at="left bottom">

    <p:menuitem action="#{documentiBean.redirectAllega()}"
        icon="menu-documentale-allega"
            value="#{cruscottoPraticaRatingBundle.allegaDocumento}"
            immediate="true">
        </p:menuitem>

    </p:menu>

</p:column>
```

For testing i'm just trying a System.out.print when i call the method "redirectAllega()" but it doesn't work. When i click nothing happens , what is the problem ? This column is inside a form.

The final method should be a redirect to another page.

Thank you.

I expect to see the message printed on console when i click the menuitem button

Answer (score 0):

could you try with ajax="false" for me (in p:menuitem tag)? I had similar case lately and that was what helped I believe

```
<p:menuitem action="#{documentiBean.redirectAllega()}"      
icon="menu-documentale-allega"       
value="#{cruscottoPraticaRatingBundle.allegaDocumento}"    
immediate="true" 
ajax="false">
```